# PHP str_replace removing unintentionally removing Chinese characters

Tags: php, utf-8, str-replace, chinese-locale

i have a PHP scripts that removes special characters, but unfortunately, some Chinese characters are also removed.

```
<?php

function removeSpecialCharactersFromString($inputString){
    $inputString = str_replace(str_split('#/\\:*?\"<>|[]\'_+(),{}’! &'), "", $inputString);
    return $inputString;
} 

$test = '赵景然 赵景然';
print(removeSpecialCharactersFromString($test));

?>
```

oddly, the output is `赵然 赵然`. The character `景` is removed

in addition, `陈 一` is also removed. What might be the possible cause?

Comment: `str_replace` is not multi-byte safe. Use `preg_replace()` instead.

Comment: I don't think you're using UTF8 to encode this data, because even if you're using non-multibyte-safe string functions it's not possible for low-order single-byte sequences like you've specified in your filter string to occur in longer UTF8 sequences. However, if your data were actually encoded in UTF16, as is most efficient for most asian scripts, this would royally corrupt the string as-stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string your using to act as a list of the things you want to replace doesn't work well with the mixed encoding.  What I've done is to convert this string to UTF16 and then split it.

```
function removeSpecialCharactersFromString($inputString){
    $inputString = str_replace(str_split(
            mb_convert_encoding('#/\\:*?\"<>|[]\'_+(),{}’! &', 'UTF16')), "", $inputString);
    return $inputString;
}
$test = '#赵景然 赵景然';
print(removeSpecialCharactersFromString($test));
```

Which gives...

```
赵景然赵景然
```

BTW -`str_replace` is MB safe - sort of recognised the poster... http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php#109937